# is every path-connected covering of the Moebius strip a Galois cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, mobius-band

Let $p : E → M$ be a covering of $M$ the Moebius Sttrip such that $E$ is path connected.

Is this a Galois covering?

My intuition is there must be some non locally path connected coverings that are not Galois. I know little about coverings of Moebius band. I know that its universal covering is $\Bbb R\times [0,1]$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since $M$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$ and a space's theory of covering spaces is determined by its fundamental group, I think you can equivalently ask the same for $S^1$ to simplify things.

Comment: Locally, a covering will look like the Moebius strip, hence it can't be nonlocally path connected. Now by William's comment, the fundamental group is abelian, so path connected coverings are all Galois

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The inclusion $S^1 \to M$ as the zero section induces a bijection

$$ Cov(M)/\cong \to Cov(S^1)/\cong $$

where $Cov(X)/\cong$ is the set of isomorphism classes of covering spaces. Moreover a covering space of $M$ is connected (respectively regular) iff its restriction to $S^1$ is connected (resp. regular).

---

**Solution to problem over $S^1$:**

The connected covering spaces of $S^1$ are isomorphic to quotients of $\mathbb{R}$ by subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$. The $n$-fold cover $\mathbb{R}/n\mathbb{Z} \to S^1$ has automorphism group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ which acts transitively in each fibre.

I think you can run a similar argument on the universal cover $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ of $M$. The covering is the quotient map of the relation $$(x, t) \sim (x + n, f^{(n)}(t))\text{ for }n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ where $f$ is the "flip" homeomorphism of the interval. The deck transformations are again $\mathbb{Z}$, which acts by $n\cdot(x, t) = (x + n, f^{(n)}(t))$.

---

**Update:** as per Max's comment to the original question, this also follows from the general theory: if $X$'s fundamental group is abelian then all its connected covers are regular.

The idea is that all the connected covers are quotients of the universal cover $p\colon\tilde{X}\to X$ by subgroups of $G=\pi_1(X)$. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then the fibres of $\tilde{X}/H \to X$ will have an action of $G$ that looks like its action on the quotient set $G/H$; if moreover $H$ is normal then this action descends to the group $G/H$ and the fibres are "$G/H$-torsors" (i.e. have a free, transitive action of $G/H$) and in fact $G/H$ is isomorphic to the group of deck transformations, hence the covering is regular. Therefore if all subgroups are normal then all connected covers will be regular.

Comment: Thank you @William. I am trying to understand why connected covers are quotients of the universal cover by subgroups of $G=π_1(X)$. Is it because of the bijection between coverings isomorphism classes and $π_1(X)$ subgroups conjugacy classes? the theory behind is not clear in my head.

Comment: Yes it is because of this bijection. Given a subgroup $H$ we get a connected covering $\tilde{X}/H$, and if we had chosen a conjugate subgroup $H'$ the resulting covering spaces would be isomorphic. Conversely, given a connected covering space $p\colon P\to X$ it is isomorphic to the quotient $\tilde{X}/p_*(\pi_1 P)$. For a reference on the relation between normality of $H$ and regularity of $\tilde{X}/H$, check out Proposition 1.39 in the [Fundamental Group](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf) chapter of Hatcher (page 71).

Comment: Actually both of the sections "Classification of Covering Spaces" and "Deck Transformations and Group Actions" in Hatcher (starting page 63) are very relevant to this discussion.